# How to store JWT refresh token on front-end and back-end sides?

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core, architecture, jwt

Client side - If we save refresh token in “Local Storage”and hacker gets this token, he/she will have access to user account forever (even if refresh token has expire date, hacker can refresh access and refresh tokens).

Server side – if we save refresh token on database, how to implement multiple Authentication. If we create table with field E.g. “UserId”, “RefreshToken”, “ExpireDate” and save several refresh tokens for single user, will it correct?

What do you advise where to keep Refresh token and why?
And what is your approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not fully aware of your problem but you might try looking at the server "Set-Cookie" response header.

This is basically a "request" from the server to set a cookie on the client. The cookie can be HTTP Only meaning that JavaScript cannot access it. It is just automatically sent to the server on all subsequent requests. Set your JWT cookie this way.

If you wrap the refresh token up inside your JWT it will be totally safe. The server can then access the refresh token for the client in question by decoding the JWT and accessing its data object.

Not sure if this answers your question but might get you thinking on the right lines.

Comment: But there is a problem, As you said, we can put refresh token up inside the JWT, but if the attacker access to the access token, our server will automatically refresh it because refresh token is always available for server even from an expired access token. right?